# Is Facebook Activity still required?

Tags: android, facebook

I started to develop my app on Android few months ago, today I found in my Manifest the following:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" ...>
    ...
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" />
    ...
</application>
```

As you can see there is the Facebook Activity. If you read the facebook doc [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android?locale=en_US) you can find:

> - Add the Facebook SDK for Android to your mobile development environment
> - Get a Facebook App ID properly configured and linked to your Android app. See - Android Getting Started, Add Facebook App ID
> - Generate an Android Key Hash and add it to your developer profile
> - **Add a Facebook Activity and include it in your AndroidManifest.xml**

But if you read the [getting started doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#app_id) you can't find any reference to the Facebook Activity. Is the facebook activity no longer needed?

Thanks

Comment: Best way to find out is to try login without FacebookActivity in manifest. I also have FacebookActivity in old project, but i don't have it in new projects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is Facebook Activity still required?

You don't need to add it explicitly into manifest. New SDK handles this for you behind the scenes. cheers :)

Comment: good to know, thanks! I guess Facebook should have say that. there is no reference here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4x